# C# Server Socket raises an unhandled exception of type 'system.stackoverflowexception' occurred in system.drawing.dll

Tags: c#, tcp, server, stack-overflow

I'm trying to receive series of pictures frames on server application and display them in picture box in the begin the program work perfect but after 5 to 10 minuets depends on how frame I send I got error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll" my code in the server look like that

```
public void ImgRecive()
    {                        
       try
       {
            tcp.Start();
            sock = tcp.AcceptSocket();
            ns = new NetworkStream(sock);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ns);
            tcp.Stop();
            if (sock.Connected == true)
            {
                while (true) { ImgRecive(); }
            }
            ns.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception exxx) { MessageBox.Show(exxx.Message); }
    }
```

I tried
 pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
and I also tried to remove the picture box and recreate it again but still have the same problem

So any idea to solve the problem guys?
[image]

Comment: You should not do this `while (true) { ImgRecive(); }`

Comment: rene thanks but it didnt help ether i still ave the same problem

Comment: the other guy @usr if u have name of tcp tutorial that may help or gave me a solution  to fix the bug i will be thankful

Comment: i think i need some thing to clear the stuck or at least to make its size bigger

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i replaced the recursion with while loop and it worked for me 
the new code is like this

```
public void ImgRecive()
    {
        tcp.Start();
        sock = tcp.AcceptSocket();
        ns = new NetworkStream(sock);
        while (sock.Connected == true)
        {
            try
            {
                tcp.Start();
                sock = tcp.AcceptSocket();
                ns = new NetworkStream(sock);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ns);
                tcp.Stop();
                ns.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception exxx) { MessageBox.Show(exxx.Message); }
        }
    }
```

thank u all guys

Answer (score -1):

See this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6sxk224.aspx

~snip

> A StackOverflowException exception is thrown when the execution stack overflows by having too many nested method calls.
>   Associated Tips
>   Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.
>   Too many method calls is often indicative of a very deep or unbounded recursion.

In addition, check for any objects/data being allocated on the stack, and try doing heap allocations instead if possible.

Comment: This is all true but how does it answer the question?

Comment: thanks for your answer but truly didnt help i know that already

Comment: Ok no worries :) Although your answer did state your problem was recursion which I pointed out, which you already knew. Cheers.

Comment: @rene see the OP's answer. I didn't have to write out the code for him, sometimes a simple nudge will do.